# Can browse SQL Server but can't connect from ODBC Data Source Administrator (64-bit)

Tags: sql-server, odbc

Installed SQL Server on Windows 10 in my home network. In setting up ODBC Data Source from another computer, using driver "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server", the SQL Server instance shows up in the dropdown for "Which SQL Server do you want to connect to?" so I'm assuming the SQL Server Browser service on the server is working fine. However, when I finish the ODBC setup and click "Test Data Source...", I get "Login timeout expired", "TESTS FAILED!".

I already opened TCP Port 1433 in McAfee LiveSafe but trying telnet server-name 1433 times out. Trying telnet on another port like 3389 (remote desktop) works fine.

In summary:
(1) SQL Server Browser is working on the network
(2) Cannot set up an ODBC connection

I have been searching online and found several solutions but none so far worked.

Thanks for any leads.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I successfully installed SQL Server on another PC on the same home network a few weeks ago and can connect to it from other computers.

Comment: Did you check the sql server configuration and or error log for what port the server is listening on?

Comment: In SQL Server Configuration Manager, I see 1433 in various places -- SQL Native Client->Client Protocols, SQL Server Network Configuration->Protocols->TCP/IP address, etc. In SQL Server Log I see only 'Server is listening on [127.0.0.1 <ip4> 1434]' and 'Server is listening on [::1 <ip6> 1434]'.

Comment: My other (working) SQL Server's log, however, also shows 'Server is listening on ['any' <ipv4> 1433]' and 'Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv6> 1433]'. I opened TCP port 1434 on the server but still can't connect from ODBC. I already have UDP port 1434 open.

Comment: It worked! I noticed in SQL Server Configuration Manager, under SQL Server Network Configuration->Protocols for MSSQLSERVER, that TCP/IP was Disabled. I enabled it, restarted the instance, and "'any' <ipv6> 1433" appeared on SQL Server Log. I was able to connect via ODBC. Thank you, Gui LeFlea.

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question with this information.